# composer create-project from self-hosted GitLab instance

Tags: composer-php, gitlab

I'm trying to use the `composer create-project vendor/name --repository=https://my.self-hosted-gitlab-instance.com/repository.git` command to create project.

When I run the command I first have to put my credentials :

```
Authentication required (my.self-hosted-gitlab-instance.com):
  Username: myusername
  Password:
```

I enter the correct credentials but then I have :

```
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                                           


Invalid credentials for 'https://my.self-hosted-gitlab-instance.com/myrepository.git/packages.json', aborting.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use URL for `--repository` value it will be treated as repository with type `composer`. If you want to use different type, you need to pass JSON with full repository configuration:

```
composer create-project vendor/name --repository='{"type": "vcs","url": "https://my.self-hosted-gitlab-instance.com/myrepository.git"}'
```

or

```
composer create-project vendor/name --repository='{"type": "gitlab","url": "https://my.self-hosted-gitlab-instance.com/myrepository.git"}'
```

> **--repository**: Provide a custom repository to search for the package, which will be used instead of packagist. Can be either an
> HTTP URL pointing to a `composer` repository, a path to a local
> `packages.json` file, or a JSON string which similar to what the
> [repositories](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#repositories) key accepts.

https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#create-project

Comment: If you have a "too many arguments" error, replace single quote by double quote and add backslash to double quotes : 

composer create-project vendor/name --repository="{\"type\": \"gitlab\",\"url\": \"https://my.self-hosted-gitlab-instance.com/myrepository.git\"}"